# central authentication and authorization System

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization, centralized

There are several different web services -- various technologies used, such as Java, .NET, Python, Perl, and possibly more in the future -- belonging to different organizations, and the access to those web services has to be restricted.

The idea is to have a central authentication and authorization server, only responsible for granting access to each Application with access rights.

I am looking for any suggestions or reference for building this application.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I don't see any question here. Could you be more precise in what you need help with ?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a federated security framework like `Windows Identity Foundation`, for example?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx

Answer (score 0):

CAS (Central Authentication Service) Server or a OpenID Server.
CAS is a bit more enterprise and OpenID a bit more Social media driven, but both work for your case.